# How many files are needed such that there is at least one math and one physics book in each of them?

Tags: combinatorics

$5$ identical maths books , $6$ identical physics
books , $3$ identical chemistry books , are needed to be saved in files on laptop desktop , How many files are needed such that there is at least one math and one physics book in each of them ?
Options: -

(A)$240$

(B)$6144$

(C)$16384$

(D)15624

Comment: There seems to be missing information.  You only need one file and put all the books in it.

Comment: Could the correct formulation be "In how many ways can we save some of the books such that every book is in the file" ?